# adding extra tab to user's profile using hook

Tags: routes

I am trying to add a `Send email` tab to all user's profile using hook_menu(). However, it's not working. My custom module name is `page_callback_test` and here's the code in it.

```
function page_callback_test_menu() {
$items['/user/%user/email_user'] = array(
    'title' => t('Send email'),
    'page callback' => '_send_email_touser',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    );


return $items;
```

}

```
function _send_email_touser(){
    return t("let's send email to this user");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works - just remove the first forward-slash from the URL you are passing to `hook_menu()`.

Correct: `$items['user/%user/email_user'] = array(`
Not correct: `$items['/user/%user/email_user'] = array(`

Be sure to clean cache after you update this.